# Как правильно заменить список, обращаясь к нему, как к ключу в другом списке?

Tags: python

```py
test = [1]
test2 = [test]
test2[0] = [2]
print(test) # [1]
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы по итогу изменить не только нулевой индекс у списка `test2`, но и само значение списка `test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы обратиться к исходному списку, квадратные скобки можно писать подряд. Замените последнее присваивание на:

```
test2[0][0] = 2
```

Comment: а если мне нужно изменить именно список, а не его конкретный элемент? Например, список test будет [1,2,3], тогда (по Вашему методу), изменится лишь первый индекс, а мне нужно изменить список полностью

Comment: замените ноль на двоеточие `test2[0][:] = [1, 2, 3]`